Normalization anomaly occurs after SG filtering of the normalized time series
I am normalizing the evi2 and pci indices, and found that after I completed the normalization, the loaded time series became abnormal. The normalized value of pci should be between 0 and 1, but I found that my pci also had negative values. I don't know if there is a problem with my normalization calculation or some other reason.
Can you provide advice?
var evi2Image = filling.select('EVI2');
var Min_max=evi2Image.reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax()).rename(['EVI2_min','EVI2_max']);
// print(Min_max,'Min_max')
Map.addLayer(Min_max,{},'Min_max')
var normalizeEVI2 = function(img) {
  var min = Min_max.select('EVI2_min');
  var max = Min_max.select('EVI2_max');
  
  return img.expression(
    "(EVI2 - min) / (max - min)", {
      "EVI2": img.select('EVI2'),
      "min": min,
      "max": max
    }
  ).rename('EVI2_Normalized')
  .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']);
};
var normalizedEVI2Col = evi2Image.map(normalizeEVI2);
// print('归一化后的EVI2:', normalizedEVI2Col);
var chart_evi2=ui.Chart.image.doySeries(normalizedEVI2Col.select('EVI2_Normalized'), point, null, 10)
// print(chart_evi2,'chart_evi2')
Map.addLayer(normalizedEVI2Col,{},'normalizedEVI2Col')
var PCIImage = filling.select('PCI');
var Min_max=PCIImage.reduce(ee.Reducer.minMax()).rename(['PCI_min','PCI_max']);
print(Min_max,'Min_max')
Map.addLayer(Min_max,{},'Min_max')
var normalizePCI = function(img) {
  var min = Min_max.select('PCI_min');
  var max = Min_max.select('PCI_max');
  
  return img.expression(
    "(PCI - min) / (max - min)", {
      "PCI": img.select('PCI'),
      "min": min,
      "max": max
    }
  ).rename('PCI_Normalized')
  .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']);
};
var normalizedPCICol = PCIImage.map(normalizePCI);
// print('归一化后的PCI:', normalizedPCICol);
var chart_PCI=ui.Chart.image.doySeries(normalizedPCICol.select('PCI_Normalized'), point, null, 10)
// print(chart_PCI,'chart_PCI')
Map.addLayer(normalizedPCICol,{},'normalizedPCICol')
var Two_index_image=normalizedEVI2Col.map(function(image){
  var pci_image=normalizedPCICol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'))).first();
  return image.addBands(pci_image.select('PCI_Normalized'));
});
var chart_TWO=ui.Chart.image.doySeries(Two_index_image.select(['EVI2_Normalized','PCI_Normalized']), point, null, 10)
print(chart_TWO,'EVI2_PCI')
var bands_s = ['EVI2_Normalized','PCI_Normalized'];
var ImageCollection_res = Two_index_image.map(function(img) {
                          var dstamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'));
                          var ddiff = dstamp.difference(ee.Date(StartDate), 'day');
                          var img1 = img.set('date', img.get('system:time_start'))
                          var result = ee.Image(1).toFloat().rename('constant')
                                          .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).toFloat().rename('t'))
                                          .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(2)).toFloat().rename('t2'))
                                          .addBands(img1.select(bands_s).rename(bands_s))
                                          .clip(roi)
                                          .copyProperties(img1,['date','system:time_start','system:index']);//[-1,1]
                          return result;
                        });
var sg_evi2_pci=ui.Chart.image.doySeries(sg_series.select(['EVI2_Normalized','PCI_Normalized']),point,null,10)
print(sg_evi2_pci,'sg_evi2_pci')

This is the code link：
https://code.earthengine.google.com/baa549f15c7b0b830325bbbcfabb6744
